# How to configure Github in VSCode?

Tags: windows, editor, visual-studio-code

VSCode has Github built in itself but I am not able to configure it. I tried it’s documentation but didn’t found anything helpful.
Do I need to install any extension to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the useful extension for VSCode, which I using now. It is simple to install & use, also has a good documentation.

[LINK](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KnisterPeter.vscode-github)

**UPDATE**
Also, there by the link is the setup guide.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I do not believe that this is an "official" extension though.

Comment: @madflow yes, my mistake about 'official', but it is useful :) answer corrected.

Answer (score -1):

Just clone your repo and open the directory in VS Code, the editor will take care of the rest.
Else you could run the `git init` command in the directory you'd like to use (on the command line/terminal) and open the directory in VS Code.

Comment: That will give you Git support.